# filterValue.toLowerCase is not a function in shadecn DataTableFacetedFilter

Tags: reactjs, next.js, datatable

I've checked everything in my data and component code, everything is seems completely fine

but I'm still getting this TypeError: filterValue.toLowerCase is not a function and also not getting the filtered value based on the selection.

If someone can help, here's my DataTableFacetedFilter component code

```
import * as React from "react";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import { Badge } from "@/components/ui/badge";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import {
  Command,
  CommandEmpty,
  CommandGroup,
  CommandInput,
  CommandItem,
  CommandList,
  CommandSeparator,
} from "@/components/ui/command";
import {
  Popover,
  PopoverContent,
  PopoverTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/popover";
import { Separator } from "@/components/ui/separator";
import { Check, PlusCircleIcon } from "lucide-react";

export function DataTableFacetedFilter({ column, title, options }) {
  const facets = column?.getFacetedUniqueValues();
  const selectedValues = new Set(column?.getFilterValue());

  return (
    <Popover>
      <PopoverTrigger asChild>
        <Button variant="outline" size="sm" className="h-8 border-dashed">
          <PlusCircleIcon className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" />
          {title}
          {selectedValues?.size > 0 && (
            <>
              <Separator orientation="vertical" className="mx-2 h-4" />
              <Badge
                variant="secondary"
                className="rounded-sm px-1 font-normal lg:hidden"
              >
                {selectedValues.size}
              </Badge>
              <div className="hidden space-x-1 lg:flex">
                {selectedValues.size > 2 ? (
                  <Badge
                    variant="secondary"
                    className="rounded-sm px-1 font-normal"
                  >
                    {selectedValues.size} selected
                  </Badge>
                ) : (
                  options
                    .filter((option) => selectedValues.has(option.value))
                    .map((option) => (
                      <Badge
                        variant="secondary"
                        key={option.value}
                        className="rounded-sm px-1 font-normal"
                      >
                        {option.label}
                      </Badge>
                    ))
                )}
              </div>
            </>
          )}
        </Button>
      </PopoverTrigger>
      <PopoverContent className="w-[200px] p-0" align="start">
        <Command>
          <CommandInput placeholder={title} />
          <CommandList>
            <CommandEmpty>No results found.</CommandEmpty>
            <CommandGroup>
              {options.map((option) => {
                const isSelected = selectedValues.has(option.value);
                return (
                  <CommandItem
                    key={option.value}
                    onSelect={() => {
                      if (isSelected) {
                        selectedValues.delete(option.value);
                      } else {
                        selectedValues.add(option.value);
                      }
                      const filterValues = Array.from(selectedValues);
                      column?.setFilterValue(
                        filterValues.length ? filterValues : undefined
                      );
                    }}
                  >
                    <div
                      className={cn(
                        "mr-2 flex h-4 w-4 items-center justify-center rounded-sm border border-primary",
                        isSelected
                          ? "bg-primary text-primary-foreground"
                          : "opacity-50 [&_svg]:invisible"
                      )}
                    >
                      <Check className={cn("h-4 w-4")} />
                    </div>
                    {option.icon && (
                      <option.icon className="mr-2 h-4 w-4 text-muted-foreground" />
                    )}
                    <span>{option.label}</span>
                    {facets?.get(option.value) && (
                      <span className="ml-auto flex h-4 w-4 items-center justify-center font-mono text-xs">
                        {facets.get(option.value)}
                      </span>
                    )}
                  </CommandItem>
                );
              })}
            </CommandGroup>
            {selectedValues.size > 0 && (
              <>
                <CommandSeparator />
                <CommandGroup>
                  <CommandItem
                    onSelect={() => column?.setFilterValue(undefined)}
                    className="justify-center text-center"
                  >
                    Clear filters
                  </CommandItem>
                </CommandGroup>
              </>
            )}
          </CommandList>
        </Command>
      </PopoverContent>
    </Popover>
  );
}
```

I've already tried changing the values of the column alos tried entering the code as it is given in  shadecn tasks example github repo, but nothing worked.

I want to get rid of this filterValue.toLowerCase() type error and filtered my data on the datatable based on the selection of facetedfilter.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/shadcn-ui/ui/issues/934) in shadcn repo, you need to add a filtering function in the columns definition as well.

Answer (score 0):

**In the `columns.tsx` file you should add the following**

```
    export const columns: ColumnDef<Users>[] = [
    {
        accessorKey: "id",
        filterFn: (row, id, value) => {
            return value.includes(row.getValue(id))
        },
        header: "ID",
    },
    ...
```